# Запись в начало строки

Tags: c

Нужно записать несколько символов в начало строки.

```
char string[20] = "1111";
int count = 2; //к-во символов какое нужно дописать
int i, length = strlen(string);
int endstr = length;
for (i = length + count - 1; i == 0; i--) {
    string[i] = string[endstr]; //пишем в новый конец строки
    endstr--;
}
if (i == length + count) {
    string[length + count] = 0;
} //запись 0 символа в конец строки
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    string[i] = '0'; //запись символов в начало строки
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вам нужно из строки "2345" сделать строку "11112345"?, так?

Comment: c 1111 получить 001111, не используя стандартные функции

Comment: *не используя стандартные функции* -- заскок преподавателя или мазохизм?

Comment: для того чтобы понять как работает алгоритм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[20];
    int i;
    strcpy(s, "1234");
    printf("before: \"%s\"\n", s);
    int l = strlen(s);
    int plus = 2;
    for (i = l; i >= 0; --i) // копируем строку смещая на plus позиций вперед
        s[i + plus] = s[i];  // включая завершающий '\0'
    for (i = 0; i < plus; ++i) // заполняем первые plus позиций
        s[i] = '0';
    printf("after: \"%s\"\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Позволю себе, спустя полгода, дополнить ответ. Абсолютно правильное решение дал @VladFromMoscow. Вообще, если задача решается с помощью функций стандартной библиотеки, правильно использовать стандартную библиотеку. Но (личное мнение), с методической точки зрения, бывает полезно написать собственный велосипед, дублирующий стандартный  функционал. Просто для тогог, чтобы лучше понять, как все это работает "под капотом".

Answer (score 3):

Все можно сделать, используя стандартные C функции, объявленные в заголовке `<string.h>`.

Например,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char string[20] = "1111";
    size_t count = 2;

    memmove( string + count, string, strlen( string ) );
    memset( string, '0', count );

    puts( string );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
001111
```

Если строка не дополнена нулями, то копировать надо не `strlen( string )` символов, а `strlen( string ) + 1` символ.

То есть в общем случае правильно будет записать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char string[20] = "1111";
    size_t count = 2;

    memmove( string + count, string, strlen( string ) + 1 );
    //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    memset( string, '0', count );

    puts( string );

    return 0;
}
```

Как в своем комментарии указал **Pink Tux**, в общем случае вы должны проверять, содержит ли исходный массив достаточно места, чтобы можно было сдвинуть вправо хранящуюся в нем строку.

Comment: Влад, законно ли после `char string[20] = "1111"` пытаться что-то поменять в `string`?

Comment: В общем случае я бы поостерёгся подобных фокусов в принципе :) Как вариант - функция, выделяющая память размером `strlen(source) + prefix_length+1`

Comment: @andy.37, вполне законно, но чревато неприятностями типа вылета за размер `string`.

Comment: @andy.37 Ваш вопрос звучит следующим образом: законно ли менять значения элементов массива после его объявления.:) Если бы это было не возможно, то тогда массивы в C++ должны выделяться динамически, как, например, в C# и быть константными как строки в C#.

Comment: @PinkTux Никаких "фокусов" здесь нет.:) Это обычная работа с массивами.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а то что мы присваеваем массиву (сиречь указателю) указатель на *литерал* разве не меняет в корне дело?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, *Это обычная работа с массивами* -- без указания предельного размера, я про это.

Comment: @andy.37 Где вы видите указатель?! Объявление   char string[20] - это объявление массива, а не указателя.

Comment: @PinkTux Как можно объявить массив в C++, не указывая его размера?. Размер массива всегда известен. Если вы волнуетесь, что можете выйти за пределы массивы, то используя и обычный оператор индексирования operator [] вы можете выйти за пределы массива.:)

Comment: *Размер массива всегда известен* -- и в вашем коде совершенно не учитывается. *Если вы волнуетесь, что можете выйти за пределы массивы* -- свой вариант решения проблемы в этом частном случае я указал в первом же комментарии к этому ответу.

Comment: @PinkTux Чем мой код отличается от примеров кода в других ответах? Но если вы боитесь выйти за пределы массива, то вы можете вставить условие, как, например, if ( strlen( array ) + count < sizeof( array ) { /*...*/ }

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, правильно я понимаю, что `char s[20] = "1234";` создает массив char размера 20 и инициализирует его как `['1', '2', '3', '4', '\0', неизвестно что]`?

Comment: @andy.37 В объявлении массива указано, что он содержит 20 элементов. Поэтому сколько вы указали в его объявлении элементов, столько он и будет содержать. Что касается инициализации, то на самом деле он будет инициализирован как { '1', "2', '3', '4', '\0', '\0',..., '\0' }; То есть все элементы, не инициализированные явно, будут инициализированы нулями.

Comment: @PinkTux Я так понимаю, что вы хотели сказать, что при выполнении подобных операций в общем случае следует проверять, содержит ли массив достаточно места для сдвига его элементов. Естественно, если места не хватает, то требуется избрать другое хранилище, как, например, динамически выделить память.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо, разобрался

Comment: можно явно добавить в ответ: `if (strlen(string) + count < sizeof string) { memmove...}`

Answer (score 2):

В принципе всё правильно, кроме одной строки:

```
for (i = length + count - 1; i == 0; i--) {
```

А надо бы:

```
for (i = length + count; i >= count; i--) {
```

И это (в вашем случае) лишнее:

```
if (i == length + count) {
    string[length + count] = 0;
}
```

---

С учётом обсуждений про выход за границы массива (ну и уж со стандартными функциями...)

```
static char *_pad_string(const char *src, char c, size_t n, int from_start)
{
    size_t src_length = strlen(src);
    char *dest = malloc(n + src_length + 1);
    if (dest) {
        memcpy(dest + (from_start ? n : 0), src, src_length);
        memset(dest + (from_start ? 0 : src_length), c, n);
        dest[n + src_length] = 0;
    }
    return dest;
}

/* inline */char *pad_left(const char *src, char c, size_t n)
{
    return _pad_string(src, c, n, 1);
}
/* inline */char *pad_right(const char *src, char c, size_t n)
{
    return _pad_string(src, c, n, 0);
}
```